# For loop and get Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a for loop like :

```
for(i=0; i<6; i++)
{
if(i=0)
{a1 = '<div>something1</div>';}
if(i>=1 & i<=5)
{b1 = '<div>something2</div>';}
}
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = a1 + b1;

<div id='example'></div>
```

Result just have : `<div>something1</div><div>something2</div>`

I want result :

```
<div>something1</div>
<div>something2</div>
<div>something2</div>
<div>something2</div>
<div>something2</div>
<div>something2</div>
```

How can I do this with `for loop` above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Insert a `<br>` at the end of of each iteration of your for-loop. I imagine that should help.

Comment: `i=0` should be `i===0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the same variable `b` instead of appending values to it.

One solution I would use in such a case is to use a array(updated to use 2 arrays to support much complete cases in which there could be a/b values interchangeably appearing).

```
var array1 = [], array2 = [];
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (i = 0) {
        array1.push('<div>something1</div>');
    }
    if (i >= 1 & i <= 5) {
        array2.push('<div>something2</div>');
    }
}
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = array1.join('') + array2.join('');
```

or use string concatenation

```
var a = '',
    b = '';
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (i = 0) {
        a1 += '<div>something1</div>';
    }
    if (i >= 1 & i <= 5) {
        b1 += '<div>something2</div>';
    }
}
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = a1 + b1;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Your answer is very good. I did it with your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; i<6; i++)
{
if(i==0)
{a1 = '<div>something1</div>';}
if(i>=1 && i<=5)
{b1 = '<div>something2</div>';}
}
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = a1 + b1;

<div id='example'></div>
```

Check out a introductory JavaScript reference. `=` is the assignment operator. Use `==` to check for equality, `&&` for logical AND.

Answer (score 1):

```
var append_data;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if(i == 0){
        append_data += '<div>something1</div>';
    }else{
         append_data += '<div>something2</div>';
    }
}
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = append_data;
```

Comment: Thanks your help. It's actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following Code :

```
var a1='';
var b1='';
for(i=0; i<6; i++)
{
   if(i==0)
   {
      a1 = '<div>something1</div>';
   }
   else if(i<6)
   {
      b1=b1+ '<div>something2</div>';
   }
}
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = a1 + b1;
```